# How to make FindFit skip data points?

Tags: fitting, filtering

I have data which looks something like this:

[image: invalid points]

And I want to approximate it with a line

The points below the line are outliers, and I  want to ignore them when estimating a and b in `a*x + b`

What is the best way to accomplish this in mathematica?

Here's the sample data:

```
{{0, -1.46871}, {1, -0.960396}, {2, -0.933101}, {3, -0.193156}, {4, 
-0.787081}, {5, 0.349225}, {6, -1.04288}, {7, -0.641152}, {8, 
  0.44213}, {9, 0.335079}, {10, 1.62793}, {11, 2.09465}, {12, 
  0.692115}, {13, 2.58813}, {14, 2.06381}, {15, 3.35164}, {16, 
  2.71424}, {17, 2.81021}, {18, 3.09869}, {19, 3.54265}, {20, 
  4.84738}, {0., -9.16012}, {5.09981, -8.19077}, {10.1996, -5.36297}, 
{15.2994, -3.10673}}
```

Comment: You can select all of the points whose ordinate is greater than -2 by evaluating `Select[data, #[[2]] > -2 &]`, where `data` is your list of points.

Comment: Yes, but I want to automate the process. And the data set and outliers are not guaranteed to have a horizontal divider

Comment: Possible duplicate of "[Filtering and Replacing outliers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/37643/280)" and "[How to remove outliers from data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/81121/280)."

Comment: "And the data set and outliers are not guaranteed to have a horizontal divider"...You will have to decide on a criteria to eliminate the points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`FindClusters`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindClusters.html)and select the required data.

```
dataFilt = FindClusters[data] // First;
lm = LinearModelFit[dataFilt, x, x]
```

[image]

```
Show[ListPlot[data], Plot[lm[x], {x, 0, 20}], Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Tried FindClusters. It finds only 1 cluster on the example data, and that does not exclude the points in question

Comment: @ArsenZahray I'm on version 11.1.0. I just checked it on 10.4.1 and it returns a single cluster. Looks like they have improved `FindClusters[]` function in the recent releases.